# Iframe loads front page but content is then unresposnive

Tags: configuration

I am trying to load an osCommerce installation within a Joomla iframe.  I can get the front page to load but then if I click on anything within the iframe it is unresponsive.  I can run the osCommerce session directly and it works fine.  Both Joomla and osCommerce are using a shared SSL.  You can see the joomla site at www.lloydsyachtclub.xyz and the oscommerce site at www.lloydsyachtclub.xyz/merchandise.

I'm pretty sure it must be something to do with the settings around https - but have exhausted changing every variable in both packages.  Any suggestions??

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work for me in Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you using, and does it work on different browsers for you?  (I am assuming you mean the iframe on the Buy Club Merchandise link, and by responsive you mean the ability to click and browse around the os commerce site within the iframe - as opposed to responsive design)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean.  I'm on an ipad (trying to build the site whilst on the move) using Safari - and when I click around the front page of the merchandise section nothing is happening.  I will try with chrome and see if that works.  At least then I will know it is the browser rather than the underlying configuration!

Comment: So I just tried it in chrome and if I type in starting with www it is working, if I type it in with the https:// in front then I get the green padlock on the home page but I have the same problem - it stops when I go to merchandise - so it is definitely something about it not working in a https environment.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is that your links on the osCommerce site are a mix of secure and insecure pages.   When loading it via a https page, an iframe sandbox prevents the insecure links from working.

When I was able to replicate your problem on a desktop PC, the links to checkout still work, as these are https.

I'm not familiar with osCommerce, but I'd imagine there is a configuration setting to force all links to be https, and hopefully that should solve it.

Comment: If there is a way to force all of osCommerce to be secure I'm struggling to find it.  If in the iframe URL I remove the s from https then it works - but i then lose the secure icon from the whole of the Joomla site (instead getting a non-secure warning icon).  I wouldn't mind if the checkout process in the osCommerce site was at least showing as secure - but it doesn't - the whole process shows as insecure.

Comment: Have you made all these changes to your config - https://www.host1plus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/oscommerce/oscommerce-administration/installing-ssl-to-oscommerce ?  (The fact this example sets the value of HTTP_SERVER  to the secure URL doesn't seem too logical, but it may work if you can't force links to use https via the admin)

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that a try.  Endeavouring to fix this around the day job so will post back once I have a chance to follow your suggestion.

Comment: A late follow up - but changing the http server to definition to be https - as per your suggestion - seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!!!